# SequelizeJS relations, same model

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I want to create a model that looks like this :

```js
var category = db.define('category', {
    name: {
      type: Types.STRING,
    },
    position: {
      type: Types.INTEGER
    }
  }, {
    classMethods:{
      associate: function (models) {
        category.belongsTo(models.category);
        category.hasMany(models.category);
      }
    }
  });
```

It works in my database, I have "CategoryId" in the category's table but when I want to include the category model on my query it doesn't work, I get an issue :

```
Error: ER_NONUNIQ_TABLE: Not unique table/alias: 'category'
```

And my query :

```
this.context.category.findAll({include: [{model: this.context.category}]});
```

Comment: Hmm you're making with the same table? I'm kind of confuse with what you're trying to do here. If you just want to find all Elements of the table category you could just do findAll.

Comment: Each categories can have a parent or children category...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to inver the order of the relations (belongsTo / hasMany)

```
var category = sequelize.define('category', {
    name: {
      type: Sequelize.STRING,
    },
    position: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER
    }
  }, {
    classMethods:{
      associate: function (c) {
        category.hasMany(c);
        category.belongsTo(c);
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Ok and that's the best way to use "hasMany" in this case? Or "hasOne" could be better?

Comment: it depends of what you want. If you just want a category to have one subcategory(child), you can just use hasOne, if you want more than one you should use hasMany.

Comment: If you're asking if sequelize has optimized relations with only one child with the hasOne, probably but I'm not sure, but with hasOne relation you can do getCategory to get the child, with the hasMany you will have getCategorys that will give you an array with all of the childs. Hope this helps :)